# Pl/Pgsql, Passing array argument to INSERT

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, stored-functions

Say I have a function with a text array parameter TEXT[]. If I do a EXECUTE FORMAT INSERT, how do I pass a quoted text string of that array to insert?

Comment: You need to provide your current code and your table definitions. **[edit]** your question do **not** post code in comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should to use `USING` clause. The dynamic SQL can use a parameters on usual places (non SQL identifiers):

```
CREATE TABLE foo(a varchar[]);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.fx(tblname text, VARIADIC p character varying[])
RETURNS void LANGUAGE plpgsql AS $function$
BEGIN
  EXECUTE format('insert into %I(a) VALUES($1)', tblname) USING p;
END;
$function$

SELECT fx('foo', 'Hi','Hello');
SELECT fx('foo', 'Hi','Hel''lo');
SELECT fx('foo', 'Hi','Hel"lo');

postgres=# SELECT * FROM foo;
┌────────────────┐
│       a        │
╞════════════════╡
│ {Hi,Hel'lo}    │
│ {Hi,"Hel\"lo"} │
│ {Hi,Hello}     │
└────────────────┘
(3 rows)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, I now know when to use using, and format. Here's my revised code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION add_property(catid INT, colname TEXT,
ty catalog_column_type, colval TEXT[])

RETURNS jsonb AS $$

DECLARE

    tn TEXT;

BEGIN

--check table exists

SELECT tablename INTO tn FROM catalog WHERE catalogid=catid;

IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_name=tn)
    THEN
    return jsonb_build_object('error','notable');

END IF;

--check if property exists for table

IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM catalog_columns WHERE catalogid=catid AND
    columnname=colname) THEN
    return jsonb_build_object('error','exists');

END IF;

IF ty='INT'::catalog_column_type THEN
    EXECUTE FORMAT ('ALTER TABLE %I ADD COLUMN %I INT',tn,colname);

ELSIF ty='TEXT'::catalog_column_type THEN
    EXECUTE FORMAT ('ALTER TABLE %I ADD COLUMN %I TEXT',tn,colname);

ELSIF ty='ENUM'::catalog_column_type THEN
    EXECUTE FORMAT ('ALTER TABLE %I ADD COLUMN %I INT',tn,colname);

ELSIF ty='BOOLEAN'::catalog_column_type THEN
    EXECUTE FORMAT ('ALTER TABLE %I ADD COLUMN %I BOOLEAN',tn,colname);

END IF;


    EXECUTE 'INSERT INTO catalog_columns (catalogid,columnname,'
    || 'columntype,columnnvalues) VALUES ($1,$2,$3,$4)' USING catid,colname,

        ty,colval;

return jsonb_build_object('error','OK');

END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```